# Transform an HList into an HList of HLists

Tags: scala, shapeless

How do I transform an HList into an HList of HLists as in the following snippet.

```scala
import shapeless._
import Nat._

case class A(i: Int)
case class B(str: String)
case class C(i: Int, str: String)

type Input = A :: B :: C :: HNil
val in: Input = A(1) :: B("b") :: C(2, "c") :: HNil

type X = A :: HNil
val x: X = A(1) :: HNil

type Y = A :: B :: HNil // could also be B :: HNil
val y: Y = A(1) :: B("b") :: HNil

type Z = A :: C :: HNil // could also be B :: C :: HNil
val z: Z = A(1) :: C(2, "c") :: HNil

type Output = X :: Y :: Z :: HNil
val out: Output = x :: y :: z :: HNil

// Illustrates what I want to accomplish.
def build(in: Input) : Output = {
  val x: X = in(_0) :: HNil
  val y: Y = in(_0) :: in(_1) :: HNil
  val z: Z = in(_0) :: in(_2) :: HNil
  x :: y :: z :: HNil
}

println(build(in) == out) // true


def magic[In <: HList, Out <: HList](in: In) : Out = ???
println(magic[Input, Output](in) == out)
```

I want to build `Output` given `Input` by way of the `magic` method that somehow maps over the input and ends up with what `build` outputs.

Comment: And what does not work?

Comment: I updated the question for clarity.

Comment: So you want that `magic` function to infer, from the input and output types, what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Basically, yes. The idea is to split `Output` into `HList`'s and then for each sublist try to build it from `Input`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't too bad with a custom type class. Note that in a sense we need two "base cases"—one to kick off the top-level `HList`, and one to start each individual inner `HList`. The inductive step then shows how to add a new item (that we know how to extract from the input) to the last `HList` we've added.

```
import shapeless._, ops.hlist.Selector

trait Picker[I <: HList, O <: HList] {
  def apply(i: I): O
}

object Picker {
  implicit def hnilPicker[I <: HList]: Picker[I, HNil] = new Picker[I, HNil] {
    def apply(i: I) = HNil
  }

  implicit def hnilHlistPicker[I <: HList, OT <: HList](implicit
    picker: Picker[I, OT]
  ): Picker[I, HNil :: OT] = new Picker[I, HNil :: OT] {
    def apply(i: I) = HNil :: picker(i)
  }

  implicit def hlistPicker[I <: HList, OHH, OHT <: HList, OT <: HList](implicit
    sel: Selector[I, OHH],
    picker: Picker[I, OHT :: OT]
  ): Picker[I, (OHH :: OHT) :: OT] = new Picker[I, (OHH :: OHT) :: OT] {
    def apply(i: I) = picker(i) match {
      case h :: t => (sel(i) :: h) :: t
    }
  }
}
```

And then:

```
def magic[In <: HList, Out <: HList](in: In)(implicit
  picker: Picker[In, Out]
): Out = picker(in)
```

And finally:

```
scala> println(magic[Input, Output](in))
A(1) :: HNil :: A(1) :: B(b) :: HNil :: A(1) :: C(2,c) :: HNil :: HNil

scala> println(magic[Input, Output](in) == out)
true
```

It'd be nice to be able to specify only the output type and have the input type inferred, but there's unfortunately no convenient way to implement that.

Comment: Very impressive. If I only knew to come up with that myself :/ I have a bit hard to follow what the code does, but I have some intuition even though I don't have the "basics" in place. `hnilPicker` is the base case, right? What does `Selector` do?

Comment: Yep, `hnilPicker` is the base case. `Selector[L, A]` picks the first `A` out of `L`—it's provided by Shapeless. I'll try to fill out the answer a bit more when I'm back at a computer.

Comment: Thanks, you are a champ! :)